# Simple and Ideal Logging in Sinatra

Tags: logging, sinatra, rack

I went through few blogs and sites which gave me some information about how to log in sinatra but didnt work for my app and also i went through a gem called [sinatra-logger](https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-logger) didnt tried it, wanted to know ideal and simple way to "log" in sinatra. Like we do logger.info for rails.

The code which i tried and didnt work is from the following site [link](http://www.nickhammond.com/2009/03/28/easy-logging-with-sinatra/) and also some of SO links were too pointing to the same approach used in the link above.

```
configure do
 LOGGER = Logger.new("sinatra.log")
end

helpers do
 def logger
  LOGGER
 end
end
```

i have written this in app.rb of my app, it fails *saying undefined method `configure' for App:Module*

Any pointers or guide would be helpful. Thanks.

**Edits**
Right Now am using file write to log my errors and messages:

```
File.open('log.txt', 'a') do |f|
 f.write "#{status}-#{CONFIG.api_url}-#{data.inspect}-tweet}"
end
```

Comment: I confirmed also that the sinatra-logger (https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-logger) didn't work in Sinatra 1.4.x.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using Sinatra 1.3 you should be able to log just like in rails with `logger.info`

The following is copied from the [Sinatra Readme](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging):

---

### Logging

In the request scope, the logger helper exposes a Logger instance:

```
get '/' do
  logger.info "loading data"
  # ...
end
```

This logger will automatically take your Rack handler’s logging settings into account. If logging is disabled, this method will return a dummy object, so you do not have to worry in your routes and filters about it.

Note that logging is only enabled for Sinatra::Application by default, so if you inherit from Sinatra::Base, you probably want to enable it yourself:

```
 class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
   configure :production, :development do
     enable :logging
   end
 end
```

To avoid any logging middleware to be set up, set the logging setting to nil. However, keep in mind that logger will in that case return nil. A common use case is when you want to set your own logger. Sinatra will use whatever it will find in env['rack.logger'].

---

[Rack::CommonLogger](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/CommonLogger) generates the log messages internally (I think).

Answer (score 2):

See my suggestion here: [Logging in Sinatra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995854/logging-in-sinatra/25330050#25330050)

However, it sounds from your question like the problem is that App is a module.

your Sinatra main class should be something like this:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
```

as opposed to

```
module App < Sinatra::Base
```

Make sure you've defined it as a class and that error should go away.