# How to print debug messages with Sinatra/Foreman?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, foreman

I'm just starting out with Ruby and with the sinatra framework. I've got a setup going now with heroku and I'm totally amazed how well it works. There is just one thing that I can't figure out. How do I debug stuff? Might sound weird but I have this variable that I'd like to print out and see, preferably in the terminal or something like that. How do I do this in ruby with forman running? When I write print or puts nothing shows upp in the foreman logging...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging in Sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995854/logging-in-sinatra)

Comment: if you do `p "stuff"` it doesn't even show up in the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `Foreman`, try adding a `log:` process to your `Procfile`. For Rails apps, my `Procfile` looks like so:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
log: tail -f -n 0 log/development.log
```

You'll want to configure Sinatra to log to a file, in my example `log/development.log`.

Locally, `Foreman` will automatically spin up a `log` process and spit the logs out to the terminal, similar to how what you see on Heroku. On Heroku, no `log` process will be ran unless you manually scale it (which you don't want anyway).