# Cant save form data using datamapper with sinatra

Tags: mysql, ruby, database, sinatra, datamapper

I am currently building a small app with Sinatra and have run up against an issue saving form data to the mysql database. Firstly I can confirm that the connection to the database is working as I am logging into the app with twitter auth and it is saving dat into its table.

The form is simple

```
route: '/'
<form action="/create" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="">Weight</label>
        <input type="text" name="weight[amount]">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" id="">
    </p>
</form>
```

The model looks like so

```
class Weight
   include DataMapper::Resource
   property :id,         Serial, key: true
   property :amount,     Float 
   property :is_goal,    Boolean, :default  => false
   property :created_at, DateTime, :required => true
   belongs_to :user
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

and the sinatra route is like this:

```
 post '/create' do
    @weight = Weight.create(params[:weight])
 if @weight.save 
    flash[:success] = "Its all saved now"
    redirect '/'
 else
    flash[:failure] = "I Didnt save!"
    redirect '/'
 end
 end
```

Now for some reason every time I enter the form is comes back with the `I didnt save` flash. Im sure this is an obvious thing but I juts cant see where Im going wrong anywhere.

Comment: Why are you not logging the errors that dataMapper returns when save fails?  Specifically, log @weight.errors - it should enumerate any validations which failed.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that do I nee to just need to output that in the view?

Comment: Thanks, your question made me realise I was missing method="post" on my form tag :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the help of logging my errors to the console thanks to mcfinnigans comment.

The database was expecting a number but as the form was using a text box it attempted to save as a string. so i added `.to_f` to my amount param to convert it.

Answer (score 2):

```
  post '/create' do
  @weight = Weight.create(params[:weight])

  if @weight.save 
    flash[:success] = "Its all saved now"
    redirect '/'
   else
    flash[:failure] = "I Didnt save!"
    STDERR.puts @weight.errors.inspect # <-- will dump the errors structure to STDERR
    redirect '/'
   end
 end
```

Ideally, though, you should set up a logger and log what you're up to.  This makes things far easier to debug.

Comment: How would I go about setting up a logger, do you know any any links?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995854/logging-in-sinatra will give you a couple of hints.